# mysql - creating table with foreign keys - error 150

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

Actually I was used this sql script to create the table scheme on mysql 5.0.24, and it was just working fine, the problem is when i tried same script on mysql 5.5.16 i get below error message:

> general error message from server: "can't create table 'amdb.am_wta_methodtree' (errno: 150)"

and here it is my sql:

```
create table AM_WTA_MethodInstance(
"ID" BIGINT NOT NULL,
"TRANSACTIONID" BIGINT NOT NULL,
"INVOCATIONTIME" BIGINT NOT NULL,
"METHODIDENTIFIERID" BIGINT NOT NULL,
"THREADID" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
"INCLUSIVETIME" BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"EXCLUSIVETIME" BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"STATUS" INTEGER(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
"EXCEPTIONMESSAGE" TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY ("ID"),
FOREIGN KEY(METHODIDENTIFIERID) REFERENCES AM_WTA_MethodIdentifier(ID),
FOREIGN KEY(TRANSACTIONID) REFERENCES AM_WTA_Transaction(TRANSACTIONID) ON DELETE CASCADE)

create table AM_WTA_MethodTree(
"PARENTID" BIGINT NOT NULL,
"CHILDID" BIGINT NOT NULL,
"INVOCATIONTIME" BIGINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("PARENTID","CHILDID"),
FOREIGN KEY(PARENTID,CHILDID) REFERENCES AM_WTA_MethodInstance(ID,ID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Comment: how did u log in into mysql. perhaps the user does not  have rights to create  a table.

Comment: actually i have the root privilege on the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the tables commit and after create the foreign key it should work.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I've created tables first, and then i tried to create foreign keys but still same error:

`mysql> alter table AM_WTA_MethodTree add FOREIGN KEY(PARENTID,CHILDID) REFERENCES AM_WTA_MethodInstance(ID,ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;`
`ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'AMDB.#sql-dbf_4d' (errno: 150)`

Answer (score 0):

The method instance table should be created first before before it can be referenced. I suggest that you create  the Tables first.

Comment: I've created method instance table first (before method tree table), and then i tried to create foreign keys ... but same result.